# Как добавить код языка в url в Nginx?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js

Сайт работает на Vue js(NuxtJS) в режим SSR. Сайт запущен в порт 3000 и через проксий в Nginx послушаю порт для домен. На сайте реализовано мулти-язык. пример урл сейчас `site.com/en` Итак задача такая. В Nginx реализовать нужно так чтобы при переходе по ссылке например: `site.com` нужно перенаправить на `en.site.com` то есть код языка должен быт перед доменом. Как это можно реализовать? И одновременно нужно валидация для код языка....допустим у меня есть 2 языка RU и EN. Нужно чтобы Nginx пропустил только эти: `en.site.com` и `ru.site.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю что будет примерно такой вид конфига (не тестировал):

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<lang>en|ru)\.site\.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/$lang;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name site.com;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://en.site.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает

Comment: @ДиликПулатов, какая именно часть конфига не работает? Подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: итак...проблема почти решено..я кое что поправил в своем днс сервере

Comment: при перенаправление с site.com на ru.site.com...направляет не правильно. вот так ru.site.com// то есть в конца добавляет два слеша. а если в ручную наберу ru.site.com все работает как надо. Потом я пробовал изменить перенаправление на rewrite ^(.*)$ http://ru.uzagent.com; все работает...не добавляет слеш в конца

Comment: и ещё одна проблема...почему-то en.site.com не работает вообще..браузер долго думает и ничего не вернет. то есть en.site.com вообще не открывает. Я пробовал добавить другие языков, они работает о язык EN не работает...странно

Comment: @ДиликПулатов, Попробуй `rewrite ^(.+)$ http://en.site.com/$1 permanent;` для того чтобы второго слэша не было. Насчет "не работает" - включи логирование, и просмотри логи сервера, чтобы определить причину.